# Capybara RSpec matchers waiting for elements?

Tags: rspec, capybara

When writing a test framework/tests using Capybara + RSpec I came across this suggestion for testing for an element NOT to exist:

```
expect(page).to have_no_button('Save')   # OK
expect(page).not_to have_button('Save')  # Bad
```

I was confused why, until I saw this was stated:

> Use should have_no_* versions with RSpec matchers because should_not
>   have_* doesn’t wait for a timeout from the driver.

Is this true? If not...doesn't it make more sense from a page object model perspective to have a method to check and return if an `<element>` exists (I usually use `.visible?`) that way you can use the rspec matcher to do `expect(page_object).to be_method_visible` or `expect(page_object).not_to be_method_visible` ?

As opposed to having to write 2 separate methods in your page objects (Unless it is true that `not_to` will not wait)

For an example of my assertion methods in my page object model, here is what I do for checking for "logout link"

```
def logged_in?
    logout_text.visible?
end

private
def logout_text
    find 'a', text: 'Log Out'
end
```

And then in the spec I would say:
`expect(page_object).to be_logged_in`

So I would use something similar for other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you came across that suggestion (maybe it's really really old) but for any "recent" version of Capybara (at least the last 4 years) when using the Capybara provided matchers it is not correct.

Assuming `have_button` and `have_no_button` are the Capybara provided matchers (not RSpecs built-in `have_xxx => has_xxx?` matcher calling a `has_button?` method you've defined on your page object) the two examples you give

```
expect(page).to have_no_button('Save')
expect(page).not_to have_button('Save')
```

will behave identically. They will both check for the existence of the button and return when it doesn't exist or raise an exception if Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds has passed and the button is still visible on the page.

Comment: Those examples were pulled from the site I saw. Basically I want to check that a button does NOT exist. Im doing page object model...so it made sense to me to make a method that returns a boolean if the button is `visible?` and then just use `.to be_method` or `.not_to be_method`. Maybe im using the rspec matchers wrong, since im using `to be` instead of `to have` But im returning a boolean value from my methods (Edit made in post)

Comment: @msmith1114 The problem is with asynchronous browser behavior you need waiting behavior for test stability -- If you're calling boolean methods then it would imply sometimes you expect it to be true, sometimes false - which of those should it wait on? With assertions/expectations Capybara can know exactly what to wait for.  If you do use boolean methods you'll probably want to disable waiting in them and then handle the waiting/stability yourself

Comment: @msmith Reading your updated question - the `logged_in?` method will never work -- if no link with 'Log Out' (should be done as `find_link('Log Out')` instead of as a CSS selector) exists (or if the link is non-visible) find will raise an exception - so it'll never get to calling `visible?` on it

Comment: How should I structure it in the page object then? Im trying to not have any selenium/capybara methods in the actual spec. I want to have a method that I can assert (within the test spec itself as opposed to having an assertion in the page object)

Comment: @msmith1114 This is exactly why page object is so opinion based. For what you want, you're probably looking at writing your own RSpec matchers (or at the very least having methods that return instances of Capybara matchers) and including them into your test class -  ie you need to end up with a method called `be_logged_in` available in your test case that returns Capybaras `have_link('Log Out')` so you can then call `expect(page).to be_logged_in` -  There are many ways you could end up with that, easiest is probably to overwrite RSpecs standard `be_xxx` behavior

Comment: Seems like im sorta just just against truthyness right? Or if it fails it's not really returning a true or false value from those methods if the element doesn't exist so it will always say it's successful? (Because right now the `to be_method_true` does seem to at least not 'fail' when testing)

Comment: @msmith1114 I don't know what you mean by `to be_method_true` but things may well work just fine until you have some asynchronous behavior on the page - or you may be returning a truthy object which will never fail, or the error messages when failing may look like they have nothing to do with what you're asserting.  ie.  Your 'is_logged_in?' method can never actually return `false` so `expect(page).to be_logged_in` may well work if the element is on the page, but `expect(page).not_to be_logged_in?` can't work.